# Prestashop Child Theme

Tags: themes, prestashop, child-theming

I have created a Prestashop child theme to a theme I purchased.
I can see my child theme (once enabled), but every time I visit the theme page to switch themes I get a 500 error.

The way I get around this is to change my child theme's config/theme.yml file. This is what I have normally which gives me the 500 error:

```
parent: parent-theme
name: My Child Theme
display_name: Child Theme
version: 1.0.0
author:
  name: "Me"
  email: "email@email.com"
  url: "domain.com"

assets:
  use_parent_assets: true
  css:
    all:
      - id: theme-custom
      path: assets/css/custom.css
      media: all
      priority: 1000
  js:
    all:
      - id: theme-custom
        path: assets/js/custom.js
        priority: 1000
        position: bottom
```

And this is what I need to have in the confog/theme.yml file in order to NOT get the 500 error:

```
parent: parent-theme
name: My Child Theme
display_name: Child Theme
version: 1.0.0
author:
  name: "Me"
  email: "email@email.com"
  url: "domain.com"

assets:
  use_parent_assets: true
```

What is it about the lines starting with css: and below that is causing this issue? Does the `– id:` need to be a reference to something above it, or has to be `theme-custom`?

Any good tutorials / reference out there that you guys can point me to, to create a child theme the right way?

My Prestashop version is 1.7.3

Thanks.

Comment: This is the most updated docs from PS: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/template-inheritance/parent-child-feature/

Comment: I saw the docs... I'm confused, so there's no need to included a reference to the child's css and js files – everything below the "use_parent_assets: true" line?

Comment: Exactly, doesn't needed, by specifying `use_parent_assets: true` you are indicating that you will use the assets from the parent theme. This is the first example documented by PrestaShop and more simple: http://build.prestashop.com/news/Child-Themes-Feature/

Comment: Ok great, but what do I do if I want to use my own css in my child theme to make my own changes? Same for JS files...

Comment: Exactly as you have done and indicate in your post, I will put an answer to print an example of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the complete guide how to achieve this on: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/template-inheritance/parent-child-feature/

But the code you will need use in the `theme.yml` file to use your custom styles/scripts files, here a complete example.

```
parent: classic
name: childtheme
display_name: My first child Theme
version: 1.0.0
assets:
 use_parent_assets: true
 css:
   all:
     - id: custom-lib-style
       path: assets/css/custom-lib.css
 js:
   all:
     - id: custom-lib-script
       path: assets/js/custom-lib.js
```

PD. It's important keep the correct tabulation, otherwise could not works.